# Emoticon in edit mode displays img tag instead of :D for example

Tags: php, html

So when user types in description :D it displays proper smiley image but when he goes to edit mode  img tag displays. I need to show :D instead of img tag. Here is the entire code:

```
$descr="some text :D";
$chars=array(":D", "^_^", ":P", ":(", ":)", "<3");
$icons=array("<img src='css/s/d.png' title='Happy' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-2px;'>"
,"<img src='css/s/donja.png' title='Very happy' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-2px;'>"
,"<img src='css/s/tong.png' title='Tongue' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-2px;'>"
,"<img src='css/s/sad.png' title='Sad' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-2px;'>"
,"<img src='css/s/gornja.png' title='Smile' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-2px;'>"
,"<img src='css/s/heart.png' title='heart' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-2px;'>"
);
$ades = str_replace($chars,$icons,$descr);

<div id="bio-data"> ///normal display mode

<i><?php echo $ades; ?></i>
</div>

<textarea id='ebio-datat' placeholder="Tell somehting about yourself" maxlength=300> ///edit mode
<?php echo $ades; ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply echo $descr instead of $ades.

So php:

```
<?php
$descr="some text :D";
$chars=array(":D", "^_^", ":P", ":(", ":)", "<3");
$icons=array("<img src='css/s/d.png' title='Happy' width='20px' height='20px'      style='margin-bottom:-2px;'>"
,"<img src='css/s/donja.png' title='Very happy' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-2px;'>"
,"<img src='css/s/tong.png' title='Tongue' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-2px;'>"
,"<img src='css/s/sad.png' title='Sad' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-2px;'>"
,"<img src='css/s/gornja.png' title='Smile' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-2px;'>"
,"<img src='css/s/heart.png' title='heart' width='20px' height='20px' style='margin-bottom:-2px;'>"
);
$ades = str_replace($chars,$icons,$descr);?>
```

Normal mode:

```
<div id="bio-data"> ///normal display mode
<i><?php echo $ades; ?></i>
</div>
```

edit mode:

```
<textarea id='ebio-datat' placeholder="Tell somehting about yourself" maxlength=300> ///edit mode
<?php echo $descr; ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

```
echo str_replace($icons,$chars,$descr);    //option 1
echo $descr;              //option 2
```

I would do option 2.

See Codepad Link http://codepad.org/StKRtPS6